# How to Change the Context Menu BackGround Color depends on DataGrid Row IsEnabled Column Value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

First, Sorry to I'm not good English.

So If you can't a problem when you read my problem,
just comments that I'll check my problem.

- I wish : I want to set ContextMenu Visibility depends on DataGrid Row in WPF
  When The CheckBox Column IsEnabled is False then I want set the ContextMenu BackGround Red
  and When CheckBox Column IsEnabled is True then I want set the ContextMenu BackGround Blue
  So Contextmenu show or not show about rows data,

Check Box Column Code

```
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" DisplayIndex="5">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                            <CheckBox/>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox  IsEnabled="{Binding testEnable}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And Context Menu

```
                                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu Name="context_memu_test">
                                        <MenuItem Header="삭제" />

                                        <ContextMenu.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
                                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=testEnable, ElementName=context_memu_test}" Value="False">
                                                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu.Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ContextMenu.Style>
                                        
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                    
                                    
                                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

I think When I Click Rigt Button to see ContextMenu, ContextMenu Check the CheckBox Binding 'testEnable' So When 'testEnable' is false then change ContextMenu BackGround Color,
or 'testEnable' is true show other BackGround Color.

1. I tried DataTrigger in ContextMenu, DataGrid
2. I make Binding about ContextMenu like Visibility={Binding proepty} but not work
3. Make the datatrigger 2 case about testEnable is true or false

plz, give me some advice